# Apply Resource Filter to all eclipse projects

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have a workspace consisting of many projects, I have the ability to apply resource filter on each specific project( say show only *.h, *.cpp files), but I'd like to apply such filter to all projects in workspace, is there some kind of way?

Comment: Are you looking for a code (language?) ? For an inbuilt/addon to eclipse? It will be pretty easy to write it in any scripting language.. but I am not sure that's what you are looking for, please elaborate.

Comment: looking to filter only cpp,c,h files, so that when I use resource windows etc it won't show all the build stuff repository stuff etc